# How to assign Textshape 1 as the title?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

With Office 2016 PPT, after sharing a PPT file and getting it back, it now has retained titles on the slides but they are now "TextShape 1", are in the correct location (top of slide), and do not show up as titles in the outline view, etc.

Merely resetting the slides overlays empty boxes.

How can I make "TextShape 1" on each of the slides to be seen as the Title for the respective slides?  A redefinition? Add a new Title box with the content of "TextShape 1", and delete the old box?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the views.

It was not easy as a vba-powerpoint beginner finding my way through the collections and terminology, and certainly time consuming, but I wrote a solution for the limited problem as presented.

You might think you could add a title object, but at least the way I tried, it complained that that could not be done with the current slide layout. I could not figure out how to designate a text box as a Title.  So I used vba to set the formats to Titleonly for slides without one, copied the text into it, then deleted the old shape that was overlaid with the new one as below:

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub newtitles()
Dim s As Variant

For s = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

If Not ActivePresentation.Slides(s).Shapes.HasTitle Then
 ActivePresentation.Slides(s).Layout = ppLayoutTitleOnly 
' adds a title placeholder too; could not .addtitle to slide without a title in format
 ActivePresentation.Slides(s).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.Slides(s).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
 ActivePresentation.Slides(s).Shapes(1).Delete ' remove redundant box
End If  'about title

Next ' slides
End Sub
```